# Second monitor detected only at startup

Tags: debian, multiple-monitors, hdmi, wayland

I'm using a Latitude E7470, with Debian 12 and GNOME on it. I'm trying to connect an acer monitor, whose model I can find if it's needed (but I believe the problem is not the monitor).

Anyway, the situation is the following:

- If I connect the HDMI cable to the laptop while it's turned off, and after that I boot the pc I have no problem
- If I do the other way around: boot and then connect the cable, the monitor doesn't pick up any signal. Opening the system settings at the page "displays" doesn't do anyting.

Now, I already had a similar problem a couple of years ago while using Ubuntu. At the time the solution was very simple, you just had to run `xrandr` on a terminal. Unfortunately this doesn't work any more since now the system is using Wayland.

Can anyone please help me with that?

Comment: See [this post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=287510). If it doesn't help, please specify the make of your display card/adapter.